# What is the difference between wrapper.instance().state vs wrapper.state()

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

When do I use `wrapper.instance().state` vs `wrapper.state()`?

It seems like instance gives me the entire object, class functions and all, so should I only use instance if I want to check everything? Is `wrapper.state()` faster in all other cases?